# Have any scholars taught on the nature of the devas?

Tags: scripture, gods, philosophy

Have any scholars set forth any systematic doctrine about the nature of the 33 devas? On what they are, their nature?

Comment: see Brahma Sutras. Here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Which sections discuss the 33 devas?